# ¿Como hago para que AJAX no obtenga una respuesta sino redireccionarme a una página?

Tags: php, html, jquery

hoy les presento un nuevo problemita, y es que ya logré hacer una validación de login con AJAX y todo bien, pero al momento de que se cumpla la condición else (sino), no me redirecciona a la pagina del perfil de usuario sino que el "header('location: profile.php');" me lo manda como respuesta de texto HTML. Les dejo los ejemplos para que entiendan mejor:

```js
   // CODIGO JQUERY 3.3.1

$('#send').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var data = {usuario : $('#email').val(), passWord : $('#password').val() };
 var request = $.ajax({
  url: 'login.php',
  method:'post',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'html',
 })

 request.done(function(response){
  $('#txtValue').fadeIn();
  $('#txtValue').text(response).fadeIn();
 })

 request.fail(function(jqXHR, textstatus){
  $('#txtValue').text("Hubo un problema al enviar los datos" + textstatus);
 })
})
```

```html
<!-- CODIGO HTML -->

<form method="POST">

   <div class="frm-cnt">

    <p class="bg-warning" id="txtValue"> Este texto contiene la validacion del login</p>

    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group">
      <label class="sr-only" for="e-mail">Correo: </label>
      <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-user"></span></div>
       <input class="form-control" type="mail" id="email" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" name="usuario">
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group">
      <label class="sr-only" for="password">Contraseña: </label>
      <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></span></div>
       <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="passWord">
     </div>
    </div>

   </div>

   <button type="submit" id="send" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-sign-in-alt"></span> Entrar</button>

  </form>
```

```
 #CODIGO PHP
 <?php 

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$password = $_POST['passWord'];

include('conexion.php');

$existUser = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT Usuarios FROM datausers WHERE Usuarios = '".$usuario."'");
$existPass = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT Contrasena FROM datausers WHERE Contrasena = '".$password."'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($existUser) == 0) {
    $info = "El nombre de usuario no es válido.!";
}
elseif (mysqli_num_rows($existPass) == 0) {
    $info = "La contraseña ingresada no es válida.";
}
else{
    header('location: profile.php');
}

echo "$info";
```

?>

Repito, no quiero que me mande el "header('location: profile.php') como respuesta sino que se ejecute esa función, es obvio que del modo en que lo hice no me funcionó, si tienen idea se les agradece la ayuda porfavor y gracias...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrias mandar como respues el `location header`

```
    // un ejemplo
    // busca la forma de obtener el contexto de tu aplicacion para no escribir localhost/proyecto/profile.php, si no que en automatico te lo obtenga el contexto de tu app    $context 
$response = array();
$context = tu metodo o funcion que obtiene el contexto

if (mysqli_num_rows($existUser) == 0) {
    $response= "El nombre de usuario no es válido.!";
}
elseif (mysqli_num_rows($existPass) == 0) {
    $response= "La contraseña ingresada no es válida.";
}
else{
      $response['redirecturl'] = $context . 'profile.php';
}


  echo json_encode($response);
```

y en tu js

```
  request.done(function(response){
            $('#txtValue').fadeIn();
            $('#txtValue').text(response).fadeIn();
// codigo para redirecionar
         window.location.replace(response.redirecturl);
        })
```

Ajustalo a tu necesidad (prueba y error)
Espero haberte ayudado!
Saludos!

Comment: Hola, no entendí lo de context, te digo que mi enlace es por raíz de carpeta, simplemente llamo  profile.php que está a la raíz, por lo que no veo cual sea el problema? , nosé , me explicas?

Comment: entonces omite la parte del contexto.  y prueba con solo la direccion del archivo de profile.php

Comment: Gracias me ayudó mucho ya resolví.